# WMI - 'Access Denied' exception thrown while reading IIS applications in remote domain machine

Tags: c#, iis, wmi, wmi-query, web-administration

Below is my code to read IIS applications in a remote machine which in in domain using WMI.

```
var connOptions = new ConnectionOptions
                                  {
                                      Username = "USERNAME",
                                      Password = "PASSWORD",
                                      Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAINNAME",
                                      EnablePrivileges = true,
                                      Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
                                  };

var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\SERVERNAME\root\WebAdministration", connOptions);

var WMIQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Application");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, WMIQuery);

//Connect to WMI
scope.Connect();

//Write the list of Applications info 
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("SiteName: {0} - {1}", queryObj["SiteName"], queryObj["Path"]);
}
```

It fails with following exception:

```
System.Management.ManagementException was caught
  Message=Access denied 
  Source=System.Management
  StackTrace:
       at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
       at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()
       at Program.Main(String[] args) 
  InnerException:
```

Remedies I tried:

1. I followed the suggestion given in [Handling Remote Connections Under UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826699(v=vs.85).aspx#handling_remote_connections_under_uac) but with no success.
   Quoting it:

> If your computer is part of a domain, connect to the target computer
> using a domain account that is in the local Administrators group of
> the remote computer. Then UAC access token filtering will not affect
> the domain accounts in the local Administrators group. Do not use a
> local, nondomain account on the remote computer, even if the account
> is in the Administrators group.

2. Added and assigned full control to the user in Computer Management -> Services and Applications -> WMI control -> View properties -> Navigate to Root/WebAdministration -> Security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by setting Authentication property of ConnectionOptions to 'AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy'

Details at : [Access Denied for WMI](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e78cf9c4-764f-4d51-95cf-3a7ccf6ad592/remote-getwmiobject-access-denied-but-wbemtest-works-fine?forum=winserverpowershell)